# unable to fix undefined index in my php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to access the token from my html page having input element having the token
when i run this page on server (wamp) in windows 7. I am getting an error as undefined index on the "api_key" . How do i fix it ?
 php code:

```
  <?php
    $Cname=$_POST['api_key'];
    if($Cname=="To-do")
    {
    $api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
    $file1="i have some url here not mentioning it for valid reason".$api_key;
    $data = file_get_contents($file1);
    $json_o=json_decode($data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_o);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
    ?>

//html page:
//script is within head
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#postJson").click(function(event){
          $.post( 
             "get_task_by_column.php",{hidden:$('#api_key').val()},
             function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);

             }

          );
      });
});

</script>
//body starts
<div>
    <form>  
    <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc" id="api_key" >
    <input type="text" id="txthtml">
    <input type="button" value="Get tasks by column name" id="postJson"/>

    </div>

    <div id='response'></div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The index in the `$_POST` is `hidden`, if you want `api_key`,  then change

```
{hidden:$('#api_key').val()}
```

to

```
{api_key:$('#api_key').val()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these

```
$Cname=$_POST['api_key'];
$api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
```

to these

```
$Cname=isset($_POST['api_key'])?$_POST['api_key']:null;
$api_key=isset($_POST['api_key'])?$_POST['api_key']:null;
```

and in js part

```
"get_task_by_column.php",{hidden:$('#api_key').val()},
```

to

```
 "get_task_by_column.php",{api_key:$('#api_key').val()},
```

Comment: thank you for your precious time,but still not working.Please help me out

Comment: @user3386765 Please check whether the parameters sent or not using firebug or developer tools ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()`

```
<?php
    $Cname=isset($_POST['api_key']) ? $_POST['api_key'] : '';
    if($Cname=="To-do")
    {
    $api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
    $file1="i have some url here not mentioning it for valid reason".$api_key;
    $data = file_get_contents($file1);
    $json_o=json_decode($data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_o);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your precious time,but still not working.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are posting will be `$_POST['hidden']` as that is what you are defining it as in your jQuery

If you want it to be api_key

Change it to

```
api_key: $('#api_key').val()
```

Comment: thank you for your precious time,but still not working.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your are accessing `$_POST['api_key']` before post api_value

```
<?php
$Cname ="";
if(isset($_POST['api_key']))
{
    $Cname=$_POST['api_key'];
 }
    if($Cname=="To-do")
    {
    $api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
    $file1="i have some url here not mentioning it for valid reason".$api_key;
    $data = file_get_contents($file1);
    $json_o=json_decode($data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_o);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
    ?>

//html page:
//script is within head
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#postJson").click(function(event){
          $.post( 
             "get_task_by_column.php",{hidden:$('#api_key').val()},
             function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);

             }

          );
      });
});

</script>
//body starts
<div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">   
    <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc" id="api_key" >
    <input type="text" id="txthtml">
    <input type="submit" value="Get tasks by column name" id="postJson"/>

    </div>

    <div id='response'></div>

</form>
```

Comment: You want me to leave the assignment of $Cname=""; itself or shall i comment it

Comment: @user3386765 first you tell me after submit which value you expect in  $_POST['api_key'] "024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc" or "To-do"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried using your code but still its not working.

Comment: expecting api key "024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php

    $Cname = false;
    if(isset($_POST['api_key'])){
        $Cname=true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['toDo']) && $_POST['toDo'] == "To-do" && $Cname){
        $api_key=$_POST['api_key'];
        $file1="i have some url here not mentioning it for valid reason".$api_key;
        $data = file_get_contents($file1);
        $json_o=json_decode($data);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($json_o);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>

//html page:
//script is within head
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#postJson").click(function(event){
          $.post("get_task_by_column.php",{api_key:$('#api_key').val(), toDo:1}, function(data) {$('#response').html(data);});
      });
    });
</script>
//body starts
<div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">   
        <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc" id="api_key" >
        <input type="text" id="txthtml">
        <input type="submit" value="Get tasks by column name" id="postJson"/>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='response'></div>
```

Comment: i want the hidden api_key which is in the inputfield of html page.the value of that hidden feild should be carried to php page in order to attach it to the url i.e $file1="i have some url here not mentioning it for valid reason".$api_key; and also want to take the input from the textbox field from the user when the page is run, and laater make comparisons and give the out put